# aar dependency error in my android project using android-maven-gradle-plugin

Tags: android, maven, gradle, dependencies, aar

I have a problem when using the aar module dependency aar module as the below issue explains.

https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin/issues/65

I have a project such like a client-server structure.

It has 3 modules:

1. `app` (my server to provide some service) -- apk module
2. `sdk` (my sdk to provide some API to communicate with my app) -- aar module
3. `common` (something which should include both in my app module and sdk module ,such as utils,beans,etc. --aar module

I do not want to write it in my both `app` and `sdk` modules, debugging and modifying should work twice.

Any idea how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you did wrong there, but I've created/modify those gradle scripts and they're working great: https://github.com/sensorberg-dev/gradle-scripts

I can see you're trying to "install" on your local maven. To do that, you have to add this line at the end of the build.gradle from the `common` module this line:

```
apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sensorberg-dev/gradle-scripts/master/publish-to-local-maven-repo.gradle'
```

and then add the metadata to the gradle.properties files, like this:

project gradle.properties:

```
POM_GROUP_ID=com.company.omg
POM_VERSION=0.0.1
POM_PACKAGING=aar
```

and common module gradle.properties:

```
POM_ARTIFACT_ID=common
```

then it's just call: `./gradlew clean installArchives`

Comment: I am using the https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin/issues/65 plugin to generate pom.xml  .  and the script to install pom is on the Jenkins ,so my project's responsibility is to generate the correct pom.xml.

Comment: And the script I showed will generate the POM and install.